# What is the real name of the Ending Theme for Fringe?

Tags: fringe, music-identification

In the American science fiction TV series ***[Fringe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fringe_(TV_series))*** (2008–2013), at the end of each episode when the final credits are shown, a beautiful 30-second-long piece is played which I found on YouTube where it is called *Fringe Ending Theme*.

Is *Fringe Ending Theme* the correct real name of that piece? If not, what is the correct name? Or maybe you know where I can get sheet music or midi of that piece?

I need its real name to find sheet music or midi for that piece for me to be able to play it myself. Unfortunately, I am unable to pick up music by ear, so I badly need music notation of that piece.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a custom piece for Fringe and is titled End Title Theme by [Michael Giacchino](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0315974/). You can find it on [Spotify](https://open.spotify.com/track/5uydBcxpEOULtp7SaC3Akm?si=yZUWW-pHQuun90XuNyTEWg) along with many of his other compositions. Unfortunately it is only 36 seconds long.

Comment: Can you provide some links to back this up?

Comment: @Valorum As I mentioned, you can find it on Spotify. It is also credited as End Title Theme on his credits in IMDB: https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0315974/

Comment: Do you have any suggestions where I can get sheet music or midi of that piece? Googling _End Title Theme_ doesn't find any...

Comment: @YellowSky I'm don't believe so, there seems to be only sheet music for the main theme unfortunately.

Comment: @moonCat93 - On spotify *where*? A bad answer makes me go look for it, a good answer leads me by the hand to where it is.

Comment: @Valorum https://open.spotify.com/track/5uydBcxpEOULtp7SaC3Akm?si=yZUWW-pHQuun90XuNyTEWg

Comment: Great, now edit that into the answer :-)